Discord's new Poll Feature - How can I automate a bot to create a poll?
Discord has gotten a new poll feature which allows to create a poll. Now, I am making a simple discord bot using pycharm and can I know how to make the bot create a poll (like when someone sends a msg like "hey lets play a game" and the bot automatically sends a poll with some options). Also what if i wanted one of the options as a variable so i could use the exact option as text in another msg (bot's msg).
I didnt try much as I know ChatGpt wouldnt know about discord's new feature as its limited to 2021.

the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example

first learn how to create this pool manually. Next try to create it when someone send standard message like /pool some-parameter. And later you may try to recognize "hey lets play a game" but this may need complex code with Machine Learning, Deep Network, Natural Language Processing, etc. So this part is too broad.

ok but i just wanted to create a poll with a prefix command, not "hey lets play a game"... is this simple?

Discord.Py has implemented the feature, but as of the time of this answer, has not yet released a new version.
In the meantime, you may need to send a request to Discord's Create Message endpoint yourself. The endpoint allows you to provide an object describing the poll you wish to attach.
